# Specific Practice Exam Website Question (Quality)

Tags: pmp

Does anyone have experience with [Exam Central](http://www.examcentral.net/pmp/question-answer) practice exam web site? Since there was just a change in the version of the test and such, I was wondering how accurately this site represents what I would see on an exam if I were to take it. I am also open to suggestions and advice on other websites that offer good current exam practices.

Comment: Search questions, list questions, and requests for off-site resources are considered off-topic. Please see [the help center](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details on how to ask questions that encourage canonical answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have experience with Exam Central, but here are a few of the resources I used. I passed it the first round. I really took as many free tests as I could find so that I did get variations. I never stuck with one practice site.

The PM-Prep Cast Team makes great stuff, but it isn't free. I'm sure that they would have their site updated.
http://www.pm-exam-simulator.com/ ($90)

One of my favorite books and approaches to teach the material was from Head First. If you don't want to buy the book, the have a free_exam here. Probably not updated.
http://headfirstlabs.com/PMP/free_exam/HeadFirstPMP_PracticePMPExam.pdf

Rita Mulcahy's Materials were always the most popular when I took the exam. They are offering a 7th edition now that says it is updated for the new test. 
http://www.rmcproject.com/product/pmp-prep.aspx

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

In a [recent survey of 100 PMPs](http://pmexamlessonslearned.com/pmp/pmp-exam-preparation-faq/7/), it was found that Exam Central is not a popular choice for free PMP mock exams as there are many better yet free alternatives available. These are (links to these can be found from the survey report linked above):

- PM Study
- Oliver Lehmann
- PMZilla Final Exam
- Head First Mock Exam (though based on PMBOK 4, but many questions are still relevant)

Of course, if you want more practice, it is advisable to invest in a paid mock exam system. PM Exam Simulator and PM FASTrack are popular choices.

Answer (score 1):

I did practice for my exam here http://www.quizlib.net. There are around 2000 free PMP questions inside. Hope this help!